# ActionScript 3 - PHP sending data via AMF (or whatever) encrypted

Tags: php, actionscript-3, public-key-encryption

I need help with two things:

1. Advice on an encryption algorithm that I can use to encode data on the server, send it to AS3 client and decode it there. From what I read, Public - Private Key sound good.
2. An AS3 library that can encode and decode that is compatible with PHP's bcrypt (again, I read bcrypt is best for this kind of data transmission).

I'm not a security expert, I hope the question is clear and not clumsy.

**EDIT:** As suggested SSL is a great option, but at the moment I am looking for non-SSL ones.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

What's your threat model? If you're only worried about people sniffing the data while it's on the wire, then use SSL. It'll be transparent to your app, and generally you only have to install a cert and change your URLs from http:// to https://

If your major threat is someone running a debugger on the app to catch the data, then you've got a massively bigger problem and will be highly unlikely to ever stop someone from "stealing" the data.

Comment: The data isn't very sensitive, but sensitive enough that I don't want to send it plain text. I thought about SSL, but at the time being it's not an option. But a very good answer. Out of curiosity, sending plain text over SSL is "risk free" - even if nothing really is over the internet?

Comment: Unless you're being attacked by someone like the NSA, it is improbable in the extreme that someone could decrypt the SSL stream in any kind of timeframe that'd leave the data still relevant/useful. For most people, attacking the server itself is far easier than attacking the communications links. Wiretapping a line somewhere only gets you a small chunk of traffic, while wiretapping the server itself gets you everything.

Comment: I see. So once you have SSL, you need not worry about encryption yourself and just send plain text data - right?

Comment: Also, why would the National Soccer Association want to wire tap me?! Haha.

Comment: @Francisc: Yes. The SSL layer takes care of everything to do with the encryption/decryption while the data's on the wire. As for soccer, there's too many TLAs (three-letter acronyms)

Comment: Haha, thank you Marc. Solid advice, and probably best way to do this, but for now our infrastructure can't work with SSL... for now. So I'll have to look for an HTTP solution to this, basically protect data over the wire, if someone has access to debugger, c'est la vie. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

A bump to @Marc B for pointing out that SSL is perfectly secure, but if you absolutely need custom encryption...

If the server supports mcrypt (most PHP implementations do), then you can use any of the encryption methods provided by mcrypt (including modern AES implementations, IDEA, TEA, etc, etc, etc [it's a long list actually]). However, the php script (of course) must be written to expect encrypted data.

Check out http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php for information about PHP's implementation of mcrypt.

EDIT: A quick dump of print_r(mycrypt_list_algorithms()) on a nearly stock fedora box with php-mcrypt installed shows...

```
Array
(
    [0] => cast-128
    [1] => gost
    [2] => rijndael-128
    [3] => twofish
    [4] => arcfour
    [5] => cast-256
    [6] => loki97
    [7] => rijndael-192
    [8] => saferplus
    [9] => wake
    [10] => blowfish-compat
    [11] => des
    [12] => rijndael-256
    [13] => serpent
    [14] => xtea
    [15] => blowfish
    [16] => enigma
    [17] => rc2
    [18] => tripledes
)
```

rijndael is AES. Some are better than others for different reasons, while some are just junk (like DES).

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Stobbe. Would you recommand a encrypt-decrypt one from the ones you mentioned. mcrypt is supported on the server. I don't have enough experience with this to be able to make an informed decision. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but if you really want to do this, you should just stick with rijndael-256 (aes-256). A couple things to keep in mind: Any block mode ciphering will be padded with nulls to fit the block size so the real length should be transited; the IV is perfectly safe to transmit (and required to decrypt), but the key is not; and--because you can't control if a someone just debugs your script--there's no way to protect the private key (as @Laurent pointed out). I wouldn't go through all this though and just use SSL. It's a false sense of security.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I was looking for a system that uses one key to encrypt and another to decrypt. Decryption on the server.

Comment: @Francisc [PHP-OpenSSL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php) uses a public-key mechanism. I don't know if AS has a built in ability to encrypt this way, or if you'd have to get another 3rd party library. I know there are multiple RSA javascript implements though which might be leveragable could be easily ported to AS)... one of them [here](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/).

Comment: @Francisc Also, a bit more poking around the interweb reveled [Forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge). It might be exactly what your looking for. I don't know if you can use it just to encrypt (rather then over a socket), but I'm sure you could modify it to do that if that's what you need.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Stobbe. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind about someone using a client-side debugger, just use an ActionScript library such as [as3crypto](http://code.google.com/p/as3crypto/), it should have everything you need to decode whatever data PHP sends.

There's no point bothering with public-private key encryption, because you'll have to embed your private key in the SWF, thus making it public.